# How to count specific characters in an Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm quite new to java,and this is my first question here, so please bear with me.

I have the below output

[image: current output]

What the values stand for ST = Spade 10, HK = Heart King, C7 = Club 7, etc.

The above output is shuffled into 4 "hands" and ordered by descending. S - H - D - C.

I'm trying to count how many Spades, Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs there are in each hand and display them respectively, so the final out put will look like this.

[image: final output].

My current code is like this. I'm stuck and have no idea how to even begin. Apologies for any mistake or if this question has been asked before

Main class

```
private static void displayStringArray(String[] cardArray) 
{
    System.out.printf("Printing from Array %n");
    for (int i = 0; i<MAXD; i++)
    {
        if (i%MAXC == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        }
            System.out.printf(cardArray[i].toString() + " ");

    }
    System.out.printf("%n---------------------------------------%n");
}

private static void transfer2D(String[][] twoD, String[] strArray)
{

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++)
            {
                twoD[j][k] = strArray[((j)*MAXC)+k].toString();
            }

        }
}

private static void sort2D(String[][] twoD)
{
    String[] row0 = twoD[0];
    String[] row1 = twoD[1];
    String[] row2 = twoD[2];
    String[] row3 = twoD[3];

    Arrays.sort(row0, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(row1, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(row2, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(row3, Collections.reverseOrder());

}

private static void print2D(String[][] strArray)
{   
    System.out.println("Re-arrange the cards");
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {   
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        for (int j = 0; j<13; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf(strArray[i][j].toString() + " "); 
        }
    }
}

private static void getHandInfo(String[] anHand, MyInt s, MyInt h, MyInt d, MyInt c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<MAXD; i++)
    {
        if (i%MAXC == 0 && i != 0)  
        {
            System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.print(anHand[i].toString() + " ");

    }

    System.out.print(s + " - " +h+ " - " +d+ " - " +c+ " - ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<PlayingCard> cards = new ArrayList<PlayingCard>();
    PlayingCard[] taCards = new PlayingCard[MAXD];
    String[] sCards = new String[MAXD];
    String[][] twodCards = new  String[4][13];
    MyInt int1 = new MyInt();
    MyInt int2 = new MyInt();
    MyInt int3 = new MyInt();
    MyInt int4 = new MyInt();

    deckOfCards(cards);
    printDeck(cards);

    listToArray(cards, taCards);
    shuffle(taCards);
    transfer(taCards, sCards);

    printDeck(taCards);

    transfer2D(twodCards, sCards);
    sort2D(twodCards);
    print2D(twodCards);

    //getHandInfo(sCards, int1 , int2, int3, int4);
}
```

MyInt class

```
class MyInt
{
    private int n;

    public void setInt(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    int getInt()
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Edit: Current Output

```
Re-arrange the cards

ST SQ SK SJ S9 S8 S7 S5 S4 S3 S2 CT CK
HQ HK HA H9 H8 H6 H5 H4 H3 H2 DT DA C4
HT H7 DQ DK DJ D9 D8 D7 D6 D5 D4 D3 D2
SA S6 HJ CQ CJ CA C9 C8 C7 C6 C5 C3 C2
```

Final Output to achieve

```
Re-arrange the cards

SA S9 S4 S3 HJ H4 DA DT D9 D7 D3 CK C4
4 - 2 - 5 - 2
SK ST S6 HQ H5 H2 DJ D2 CA CQ C8 C5 C2
3 - 3 - 2 - 5
SQ S8 S7 HA HT H9 DQ D5 D4 CT CJ C6 C3
3 - 3 - 3 - 4
SJ S5 S2 HK H8 H7 H6 H3 DK D8 D6 C9 C7
3 - 5 - 3 - 2
```

Comment: Aria, Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add the output in the description since I couldn't able to access the image which you have attached.

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar Hi Ganesa. I have updated the post. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is MAXD and MAXC?

Comment: @JohnDoe MAXD & MAXC are 52 and 13 respectively.


52 = max number of cards and 13 = total number of cards each row/hand.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following solution is a demo method, that just shows you how to count the cards. It doesn't care about duplicates or sorting, but counts the correct amount of cards in a specific suit. The first part of main generates the cards, so ignore that. Look at the code after the comment `//this is the basis for your method`. I have solved it with a switch statement, but there are probably more elegant ways to solve it.

```java
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         //this method generates random cards.
         //I dont worry about doubles for now.
        String [][] cards = new String[4][13];
        String[] suits = {"S","H","D","C"};
        int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<13; j++) {
                String suit = suits[(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
                int number = numbers[(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10)];
                String card = suit+number;
                cards[i][j] = card;
            }
        }
        //prints the first hand.
        //Note it is shuffled, but that doesn't matter
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++) {
            System.out.print(cards[0][i]+", ");
        }

        //this is the basis for your method
        int[]counts = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++) {
            switch(cards[0][i].charAt(0)) {
                case 'S': counts[0]++; break;
                case 'H': counts[1]++; break;
                case 'D': counts[2]++; break;
                case 'C': counts[3]++; break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            System.out.print(suits[i] + ": " + counts[i] + ", ");
        }


    }
}
```

And output:

```
H4, S1, S10, C2, S5, C10, S8, S1, H8, H6, C5, D1, C3, 
S: 5, H: 3, D: 1, C: 4,
```

Comment: And if you want to follow your `getHandInfo` method you could pass in a hand (`cards[x]`) and then each value of counts(`counts[0]`) as this:

`getHandInfo(cards[0], counts[0], counts[1], counts[2], counts[3]);`